Can't run JavaW
Yesterday, I installed JDK 22. And when I try to run javaw nothing happens. (Everything else works fine though) No error, no anything. Though, when I do echo %errorlevel% I still get error code 0.
I tried almost everything, reinstalled JDK, double-checked PATH, asked ChatGPT, you get it. Though, all of my attempts changed nothing.
> javaw

> echo %errorlevel%
0
> javaw --help

> javaw /?


@DuncG Alright.

Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
You need to learn to copy and paste from the console. Check the output of where javaw

@g00se Ok, sorry.

Also javaw doesn't have console so try java instead

I was about to say that ironically, the whole point of javaw is you don't see any output ;) But you've definitely got a different problem

@DuncG I am using Install4J to compile my jar to exe. And it requires javaw, that's why i'm asking this question in the 1st place.

Bear in mind that unless you have strategies in place (which you should have btw) that if there are errors in your app, using javaw will effectively hide them and make diagnosis difficult to impossible

@g00se Well, are there any alternatives to Install4J then?

Indeed. You don't need 3rd party tools at all

@DuncG I just finished installing JDK21, and nothing changed.

No problem. What was the output?

@g00se Output of what?

The command I gave you

@g00se Oh, right. I forgot ;) I get D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\javaw.exe (I have a custom installation path since my C drive is almost full)

So now try d:;javaw --help Since I know you can now copy and paste to/from cmd.exe, paste that in and tell me what you get

@g00se Same result.
C:\Users\User>d:;javaw --help
D:\>

repeating from above: javaw does not write anything to the console, javaw --help will not show anything ||| try some error like javaw -XXX - this should open an error dialog - intentionally wrong

@user85421 Now I am confused.

What are you confused? See the documentation: "The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there's no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails."

@user85421 Thank you so much, it did indeed show an error dialog.

@user85421 I haven't got a Windows machine right now. So you're saying that javaw refuses to print anything - even help?

@g00se Well, as @user85421 said: javaw was made for GUI applications. So there's no point in printing anything in the console if there is no console shown.

Well, so far, at the very least, its refusal to conform to standards has cost your time and mine ;) IOW it has violatated POLA

@g00se Very true.

@g00se I have a Windows machine ( :- | ) and it does not print ANYTHING (no console) no -help, no --show-version, no -showversion (last one should go to standard err)

At least part of this mess could be to do with the fact that Windows (afaik) has no real distinction between stdout and stderr perhaps

Oops, i accidentally made a typo while editing. ;)

Please don't add SOLVED to your question title. Either accept the answer that solved your problem, or alternatively answer your own question with your solution and accept that answer.

@TT. I know, I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.

As user85421 commented, it is normal behaviour based on the javaw documentation:

The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there's no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want
a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however,
display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails.

